# Drupal (сборка Drushop): скрыть главное меню на одной странице

Tags: drupal

Доброго всем времени.
Делаю сайт на Drupal v6 (сборка Drushop , другую связку ещё не разработали), некоторые вещи ни как не поддаются логике.
Например, с блоками - понятно, есть свойство "Показывать блок на определенных страницах".
А вот как отключить самое главное меню. Что-то не совсем ясно где это и как.
Писать функцию определения по имени страницы в page.tpl.php, это может быть выходом, но ведь сайт на CMS, должно же вроде быть предусмотрена эта особенность функционалом.

---

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не смог разобраться в мудрёной CMS...
Сделал старым дедовским способом - программированием ;)

```
<?php
            function uri_name()
            {
                $path ='';
                $path = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

                return $path;
            }
            //print uri_name();

            if (uri_name() != '/gates' and uri_name() != '/')
            {
                print theme('grid_block', $primary_links_tree, 'primary-menu');
            }

?>
```

Это если скрывать меню на центральной странице uri="/" и странице с uri="gates".

Comment: универсальных решений не бывает (я о цмс -е), и Друпал не исключено.